# Using citation marks around a variable in array access

Tags: php, arrays, string, associative-array

I'm reading som legacy code and come over a curious case:

```php
$my_assoc_array; /* User defined associative array */
$my_key; /* User defined String */
$value = $my_assoc_array["$my_key"];
```

Is there any clever reason why you would want to have citation marks (`"`) around the variable when it's used as a key? Like a very special corner case? Or is there simply no reason at all to do this?

-- EDIT -- 
Maybe in some old version of PHP there was a difference? (Remember this is legacy code).

Comment: In this specific example, it's pointless, but yours is a very very strict scenario.

Comment: @JonStirling When can there be a point to do this?

Comment: Well, as with any other double quoted string, you can build on the variable e.g. "key_$my_key". There's also the idea that `$my_key` could be an object with a __toString (though I can't for the life of me why somebody would do that). But they don't apply to the example you gave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one example that I can find where the output differs which is when `$mykey = false`.
(which perhaps does not apply to your example where $mykey is a string, but then again: this is the wild wild world of PHP)

```
<?php
$arr = array("1"=>"b", "0"=>"a");
$mykey = false;
var_dump($arr[$mykey]);
// returns "a"
var_dump($arr["$mykey"]);
// gives Undefined index error

$mykey = true;
var_dump($arr[$mykey]);
// returns "b"
var_dump($arr["$mykey"]);
// returns "b"
```

What this can be (mis-)used for beats me...

Answer (score 0):

Its not necessary to bind variable name with double quotes inside array index:

you can simply write with out quotes:

```
$value = $my_assoc_array[$my_key];
```

Answer (score -3):

it will be different one if $my_key is an integer value

```
$my_key = 3; /* User defined String */
$value = $my_assoc_array["$my_key"]; /* returns $my_assoc_array["3"] */
$value = $my_assoc_array[$my_key]; /* returns $my_assoc_array[3] */
```

Comment: You can't generate (afaik) an array with a key of `3` _and_ a key of `"3"`, so in this example both lines are one in the same.